# Where are the hidden layers?

Tags: keras, neural-network, nlp, keras-layer, autoencoder

I am a bit new to the autoencoder. I have this code from Keras (https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html). I wonder that my comments in code here correct?

```
input_img = keras.Input(shape=(784,)) # input
encoded = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input_img) # is it hidden layer???
encoded = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded) # is it hidden layer???
encoded = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(encoded) # is it hidden layer???

decoded = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded) # is it hidden layer???
decoded = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded) # is it hidden layer???
decoded = layers.Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(decoded) # output
```

If possible, can you guys explain a bit more? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden layer is any layer that is located between the input and output layers ([ref](https://cs230.stanford.edu/files/C1M4.pdf)). Therefore, all these are hidden layers in your network:

```
encoded = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(input_img)
encoded = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
```

In autoencoders, there is a hidden layer that is of special interest: the "bottleneck" hidden layer in the network, which forces a compressed knowledge representation of the original input. In your example, it is a 784 to 32 compression and the bottleneck hidden layer would be:

```
encoded = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(encoded)
```

[image]

[source](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/autoencoders/)

Comment: Is it possible to have more than 1 hidden layer?

Comment: Yes. Modified the answer.